# How to discover Subdomain from our website? / How to connect without IP

Tags: php, apache

I was now deploying my webservice. I developed a android java client where I have to use URLs with IPs. The problem is, I don't know the subdomain. For example:

```
private static final String URL = "http://apkitchen.voku-online.de/something.php";
```

It's easy to convert that url to an IP (it's also the same as FTP use) but the problem is when I enter that IP on the browser I go to other website on that domain because I have to know the alias.

-
http://81.x.x.x/subDomain/OTHER_ALIAS_MAYBE/My_files

There's any way to discover the alias, subdomain (i dont really know the right technical term in english, sorry).

Alternatively if there's a way to connect without IP, I would like to know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you _can_ reach it by IP without giving a hostname (on shared hosting, this is certainly not a given) it is a _custom_ solution by the hosting company, not something that can be 'discovered'. You'll have to ask them.

Comment: A lot of HTTP server use the same IP to serve different websites, based on the http host you put on your HTTP/1.1 request header, so accessing these servers by IP will only show you 1 of maybe 1000 websites (this is called name based virtualhosting). Accessing a webserver by IP is not equivalent as accessing it by name. Then the things you call ALIAS is simply directories, they may not even exists.

Comment: @regilero, so only asking to the hosting company ?

Comment: I can add the following information. The information I have on my panel is that hostname is "www", domain is "apkitchen.co.cc" and on my FTP I can see that my files are under "web" folder. However this was not helpfull. Also I did a PHP script to see full path I get /var/www/web27/web so I tried 81.x.x.x.x/var/www/web27/web but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are in same position, it's not possible unless you own the server or contacting the owner/manager.